# Unable to add symbol in header of table

Tags: tables, symbols

So, here is a table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{foo}            & \textbf{bar}           & \textbf{foobar}        & \textbf{fsj}           & \textbf{jifd}          & \textbf{jifd}          & \textbf{jif}                                                          & \textbf{ifi}                                                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1}                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}{\color[HTML]{3166FF} 1}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1}                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Now I am trying to change the `\textbf{foo}` (name of first column) to `\neg B` 
But I get the following error:
! Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
l.55 }

Comment: Replace `\neg B` by `$\neg B$`. And why not `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}`? (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Cool. I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Symbol Thanks for the reference. I have just got started. BBut thanks for the reference

Comment: Also, I would recommend you have a look at the `booktabs` package and avoid vertical rules.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, you need TeX's math mode for the `\neg` macro. I.e., input `$\neg B$` instead of just `\neg B`.

A much more fundamental problem with your tabular is that the code is *much* too complicated. In particular, it is simply not necessary to encase each and every cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` statement. Not only is doing so grossly inefficient, it also makes debugging far more tedious than needs to be the case. In the code below, you'll find *not a single* `\multicolumn` statement.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% define a shortcut macro to change both cell and text color
\newcommand\combinedcolor{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\color[HTML]{3166FF}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
$\neg B$ & \textbf{bar} & \textbf{foobar} & \textbf{fsj}  & 
\textbf{jifd} & \textbf{jifd} & \textbf{jif} & \textbf{ifi} \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \combinedcolor 1 & \combinedcolor 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \combinedcolor 1 & \combinedcolor 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \combinedcolor 1 & \combinedcolor 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \combinedcolor 1 & \combinedcolor 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```